# Firebase equivalent of the following mysql query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got the following three SQL tables (in MySQL):

```
Users
+---------+------+
| user_id | name |
+---------+------+
| user_1  | John |
+---------+------+
| user_2  | Jane |  
+---------+------+

Places
+-----------+----------+
| places_id | name     |
+-----------+----------+
| places_1  | KFC      |
+-----------+----------+
| places_2  | Starbuck |
+-----------+----------+
| places_3  | Subway   |
+-----------+----------+

UserLikes
+---------+-----------+----------+
| user_id | places_id | liked    |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| user_1  | places_1  | yes      |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| user_1  | places_2  | no       |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| user_2  | places_1  | yes      |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

This is the query that I used to get the places that `user_1` has not liked or disliked.

> SELECT * FROM Places WHERE places_id NOT IN ( SELECT places_id FROM
>   UserLikes WHERE user_id = 'user_1' )

I need a Firebase query that is equivalent to the query above. How would you do this logic in Firebase?

Thanks.

Comment: how does your firebase-database look like?

Comment: You should also add your firebase-database structure (in JSON, not picture). You can export the JSON file from the console.

Comment: You're asking about Firebase, but sharing a SQL implementation. This seems to indicate that you're new to NoSQL. No problem with that, it's a steep learning curve that many of us have to take at some point. I'd recommend learning a bit more on the basics of NoSQL first. Recommended reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).